# How to make a form expand as window expands?

Tags: expand

I've noticed some forms that nicely expand or compact their width as the user expands or compacts the size of their window.

Is there a name for this UX feature? I'm a little out of the loop wit UX stuff, so am not sure what to look for . Does jQuery do this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: Thanks Epascarello - found a great responsive form at http://www.formget.com/how-to-make-simple-responsive-form-for-a-website/